# How do I make a particle zoom transition using html5 canvas + js?

Tags: javascript, html5-canvas, particles

I'm trying to make a transition effect for my website similar to the one that can be found [here](http://www.mathis-biabiany.fr) when you scroll. I've searched high and low and can't seem to find anything even closely related to it. I've started looking through the code on that webpage but I don't really have the time to scour through nearly 50,000 lines of code and test to find the part that I need. The only difference I would make for my site is that I would like the particles to be circles, not squares. Any help that anyone can provide would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: the code is all at the end of the file desktop-841e6f377c020b84c060.min.js...
search for..."only required if quaternion is not already normalised"
It's a messy flat js file :(

Comment: Thank you @AnyMoose. Combined with the resources that fsinisi90 has given me you have both led me in the right direction to pulling something like this off. It sounds and looks like it's not going to be easy but I'm up to the challenge.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The creator of that site it's using [Three.js](https://threejs.org) to accomplish that effect. It's not easy to achieve.

These examples might help you but you should learn [the basics](https://threejs.org/docs/index.html#manual/introduction/Creating-a-scene) first.

- https://threejs.org/examples/#webgl_modifier_tessellation
- https://threejs.org/examples/#webgl_gpu_particle_system

Comment: Thank you. You have given me some good resources to work with and learn this. I've come across three.js in my search but wasn't sure that was what I was needing. I appreciate the resources.